# I cannot uninstall debug apk from my phone

Tags: android

I cannot uninstall debug APK manually which I installed directly from Android studio, and also I can't install the debug APK manually in the phone. I have the released version of the same app installed from play store on my phone.

Comment: how exactly you can't uninstall it? What stops you from uninstalling? What exactly is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

it may be, you have multiple users on your device, just go settings->Apps->Select your app->open the context menu on the right and type uninstall for all users.

--Edit:

[image: Select context menu in the upper right]

[image: Here is the uninstall for all users (My device Sony Xperia Z5)]

Comment: sorry, did you mean, uninstall through settings?
I tried that already, but not worked.
The uninstall issue I've seen on Asus mobile, and also in Samsung S6.

Comment: no I mean to uninstall it for all users, you need to open the apps from settings and select your app and open the context menu or find where you can uninstall the application for all users on your device and the application will be uninstalled

Comment: I have edited my answer with picture for more clarifications, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

from next time user command `adb install -r --user 0 <apk file path>`

And when you uninstall with `adb uninstall <pkg name>`, it only uninstalls from `user 0`
so, apk is still installed for other users. And you have to go to `settings->Apps->Select your app->open the context menu on the right and type uninstall for all users`